# How to get a series from two other series?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, binding, series

I'm building an XYChart in JavaFX. It contains two series (series 1&2) and a third series (series 3), which values should be the sum of series 1 & 2.

Now, series 3 should automatically update, if changes on the values (adding, removing, changing etc. ) of series 1 or 2 are done.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

```
package lineChart;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();


        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 10));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 30));
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 20));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 30));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 40));
        lineChart.getData().add(series2);

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        // series3 = series1 + series2
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 10 + 20));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 20 + 30));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 30 + 40));
        lineChart.getData().add(series3);



        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update 1**
I've updated the example code. If I run this code series 3 reacts on adding or removing data objects from series 1 or series 2. But unfortunately it does not react on changing the values of the data objects.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    private static int updateCounter = 1;

    private XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer> series1, series2, series3;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final LineChart<Integer, Integer> lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);

        series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 10));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 30));
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);

        series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 20));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 30));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 40));
        lineChart.getData().add(series2);

        series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        lineChart.getData().add(series3);
        bindDataSeieses();

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // update 1
        updateSumSeries();
        // update 2
        series1.getData().remove(0);
        // update 3
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 50));
        // No update :-(
        series1.getData().get(0).setYValue(200);

    }

    private void bindDataSeieses() {

        series1.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<Data<Integer, Integer>>) c -> updateSumSeries());
        series2.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<Data<Integer, Integer>>) c -> updateSumSeries());

    }

    private void updateSumSeries() {

        System.out.println("Update " + updateCounter++);
        // todo enhance to support series of different length
        if (series1.getData().size() != series2.getData().size())
            return;
        series3.getData().clear();
        for (int index = 0; index < series1.getData().size(); index++) {

            int xValue = series1.getData().get(index).getXValue();
            int yValue = series1.getData().get(index).getYValue() + series2.getData().get(index).getYValue();
            series3.getData().add(new Data<>(xValue, yValue));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you can't get the two series, sum them, and add them to the third series.

Comment: Series 3 should automatically update, if changes on the values (adding, removing, changing etc. ) of series 1 or 2 are done.

Comment: How are you changing the data?

Comment: Actually I'm changing the data by dragging the nodes of the plotted series in the chart. It's not in the example code to keep it as simple as posible.

Comment: Modifying a question after it has been answered is not a good practice.

Comment: The Question was not modified. It was appended by an Update. When I push the Button, than series 1 (the red one) moves ist first entry to 200. **But:** Series 3 does not move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve dynamic update of the 3ed series by adding listeners to the two others:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    private  XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer> series1, series2, series3;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final LineChart<Integer, Integer> lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 10));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 30));
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);

        series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 20));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 30));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 40));
        lineChart.getData().add(series2);

        series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        lineChart.getData().add(series3);
        bindDataSeieses();

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void bindDataSeieses() {

        series1.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<Data<Integer, Integer>>) c -> updateSumSeries());
        series2.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<Data<Integer, Integer>>) c -> updateSumSeries());

        updateSumSeries();
    }

    private void updateSumSeries() {

        //todo enhance to support series of different length
        if(series1.getData().size() != series2.getData().size())
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("series1 and series2 must be of same length");
        series3.getData().clear();
        for (int index = 0; index < series1.getData().size(); index++){

            int xValue = series1.getData().get(index).getXValue();
            //todo verify series1.getData().get(index).getXValue() == series2.getData().get(index).getXValue()
            int yValue = series1.getData().get(index).getYValue() + series2.getData().get(index).getYValue();
            series3.getData().add(new Data<>(xValue, yValue));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**  response to the updated code: 
update 1 is not needed. `updateSumSeries()` is invoked by the listener. 
update 2 makes `series1.getData().size() != series2.getData().size()`  be true so `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. Watch your exceptions.

The following code demonstrates and edit with a click of a button:

```
public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    private  XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer> series1, series2, series3;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final LineChart<Integer, Integer> lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);

        series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();

        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 10));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 20));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 30));
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);

        series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 20));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 30));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 40));
        lineChart.getData().add(series2);

        series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        lineChart.getData().add(series3);
        bindDataSeieses();

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(lineChart);
        Button btn = new Button("Add");
        btn.setOnAction(e->series1.getData().set(0, new Data<>(1, 200)));
        root.setBottom(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void bindDataSeieses() {

        series1.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<Data<Integer, Integer>>) c -> updateSumSeries());
        series2.getData().addListener((ListChangeListener<Data<Integer, Integer>>) c -> updateSumSeries());

        updateSumSeries();
    }

    private void updateSumSeries() {

        //todo enhance to support series of different length
        if(series1.getData().size() != series2.getData().size())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("series1 and series2 must be of same length");
        series3.getData().clear();
        for (int index = 0; index < series1.getData().size(); index++){

            int xValue = series1.getData().get(index).getXValue();
            //todo verify series1.getData().get(index).getXValue() == series2.getData().get(index).getXValue()
            int yValue = series1.getData().get(index).getYValue() + series2.getData().get(index).getYValue();
            series3.getData().add(new Data<>(xValue, yValue));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Series 3 reacts on adding and removing data from series 1 & 2. How could I manage that Series 3 also reacts to the change of a data object (e.g. series1.getData().get(0).setYValue(200)).

Comment: It does. `series1` as well as `series2` have a `ListChangeListener` registered. The `ListChangeListener` responds to edits as well a add and remove.

Comment: Dear c0der, thank you for your patience. I've altered the code a bit. Unfortunately it is not working for me? Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: See my edited answer. Changing the question after is has been answered is not recommended because it makes answers irrelevant or not full. For new question please make a new post.

Comment: Dear c0der. Update should be called after series1.getData().get(0).setYValue(200); But it is not called.

Comment: `series1.getData().get(0).setYValue(200);` does not do what you think it does. You removed element at 0 by `series1.getData().remove(0);` so `series1.getData().get(0).setYValue(200);` changes the next one. After removing 0 you can add it by `series1.getData().add(0, new XYChart.Data(1, 200));`.

Comment: Dear c0der. Thank you for your hint. But for this question it doesn't matter which entry is changed. I do expect a call of the update method on the Change of any value of series 1 or series 2.

Comment: Dear c0der. My question ist not answered yet.

Comment: I apologize, but the ListChangeListener does not respond to Edits.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I made a mistake in the comment. What I wrote in my previous comment is correct : "After removing 0 you can add it by `series1.getData().add(0, new XYChart.Data(1, 200));`"   You can also edit by `series1.getData().set(0, new Data<>(1, 200))`  **not** by `series1.getData().get(0).setYValue(200);`